# How to get the result of the model.predict() method

Tags: yolo, predict, pyqt6

I have a fragment of code for a model that segments cells:

```
model = YOLO(FileModelPath)
predictions = model.predict(img, show = False, classes=[0,1], save = True,project='YourPhoto' ,name=Ui_MainWindow.FILENAME, show_labels = False, show_conf = False,save_txt = True, conf=float(text), line_thickness=1)
```

after the work is completed, the method outputs data to the console:

`0: 640x640 7 Explode cells, 78 Whole cells, 402.8ms`

`Speed: 4.9ms preprocess, 402.8ms inference, 161.3ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)`

The question is, how do I get this data in the code? So that I can output them in my gui?

Answer (score 0):

Only use:

print(predictions[0].speed)

***example output***

*{'preprocess': 0.0, 'inference': 25.67434310913086, 'postprocess': 6.798505783081055}*